# RxBluetoothKit: How to subscribe to Bluetooth state + Peripheral connection state and Write/Notify characteristics at same time?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I just started to study about RxBluetoothKit as easy solution to interact with BLE devices and I have very basic knowledge of Rx programing.

As i can see from examples, every time i have to write some characteristic i have to scan + establishConnection to Peripheral + discover Services and only then write and subscribe for confirmation of this specific Characteristic.

Same happen for read Characteristic.

If I understand correctly,  this way I can subscribe only to one sequence/ connection at same time.

But what i need is to subscribe to Bluetooth state and to Peripheral connection state and to notify Characteristic, in addition i have send write commands to same Peripheral sometimes.

Need help to understand how should i handle this scenario by using RXBluetoothKit library?
Links to similar approachment on GitHub are welcomed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact case isn't covered by RxBluetooth kit, so you'll have to manage this case by yourself. Not the most ideal, but you could go with something like this:

```
// Get an observable to the Peripheral, then share it so
// it can be used for multiple observing chains
let connectedPeripheral: Observable<Peripheral> = peripheral
    .establishConnection()
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)

// Establish a subscription to read characteristic first
// so no notifications are lost
let readDisposable = connectedPeripheral
    .flatMap { $0.observeValueAndSetNotification(for: Characteristic.read) }
    .subscribe()

// Write something to the write characteristic and observe
// responses in the chain above
let writeDisposable = connectedPeripheral
    .flatMap { $0.writeValue(data, for: Characteristic.write, type: .withResponse) }
    .subscribe()
```

The example above is just a gist, but the general idea should work since I'm doing a similar thing in a project of my own. Be careful to dispose the observables when done, either by .take or disposeBags.